# no login prompt in .htaccess from browser

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, httpd.conf

I'm trying to protect a directory (/var/www/html/user) using .htaccess. The directory basically has index.php which renders an html page as follows:

```
<?php    
$login=$_SERVER['USER'];

if(isset($login)) {
// Output HTML content
}
else {
echo "
<html>
<body>
<center>
User not recognized!
</center>
</body>
</html>
";
}
?>
```

My .htaccess file is:

```
AuthName "IT web"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /remote/wwwin/LDAP_DB/dir-user-passwd
<Files index.php>
require valid-user
</Files>
```

When I try to access index.php from the browser, I do not get a prompt to login and the html in the else condition is displayed (i.e, User not recognized!)

> Server version: Apache/2.2.3

I have also verified in the httpd.conf file that

> AccessFileName .htaccess

Would be grateful if someone can help me identify the issue.

Cheers!!

Comment: did you check if .htaccess usage is even enabled? it's normally off for efficiency. e.g. `AllowOverride all`

Comment: Yes Marc, htaccess is enabled. I just checked in httpd.conf file: 

    AllowOverride All

Answer (score 0):

You're checking the wrong $_SERVER variables. HTTP basic auth data in PHP goes into `PHP_AUTH_USER` and `PHP_AUTH_PW` keys, not `USER`.

See Example #1 here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php

```
if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) { ... not logged in ... }
```